# FactoryGirl using :parent => associations fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following tables:

```
  create_table "acs_objects", :force => true do |t|
     #various attributes....
  end


create_table "content_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.string   "name"                     :limit => 400
end
```

In AR, this relation holds:  class ContentItem < AcsObject

My Rspec test is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ContentItem do

  subject {Factory(:content_item)}
  it {should be_valid}

end
```

If I define the factory like this:

```
Factory.define :content_item do |ci|
  ci.sequence(:name) {|n| "Music#{n}"}
end
```

I get an error: null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint

If I change the factory this way:

```
Factory.define :content_item, :parent => :acs_object do |ci|
  ci.sequence(:name) {|n| "Music#{n}"}
end
```

then I get this error:

NoMethodError in 'ContentItem '
undefined method `name=' for AcsObject:0xb3ee51e8

I have used :parent before and never had this problem.  'name' clearly belongs to ContentItem - why am I getting this error?

I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to the fact that the content_items table is defined as a view, and the mix of parent and child attributes:

```
View definition:
 SELECT parent.id, parent.object_type, parent.context_id, parent.security_inherit_p, parent.created_by, parent.created_at, parent.created_ip, parent.updated_at, parent.updated_by, parent.updated_ip, parent.context_tree_sortkey, parent.context_max_tree_sortkey, child.parent_id, child.name, child.locale, child.live_revision AS live_revision_id, child.latest_revision AS latest_revision_id, child.publish_status, child.content_type, child.storage_type, child.storage_area_key, child.tree_sortkey, child.max_child_sortkey
   FROM acs_objects parent
   JOIN cr_items child ON parent.id = child.item_id;
```

If this is indeed the cause, is there any way to use FactoryGirl and have it work as expected?

Update:  the ContentItem factory now works.  Here's the change I made:

```
Factory.define :content_item do |ci|
  ci.sequence(:name) {|n| "Music#{n}"}
  ci.parent_id      Factory(:acs_object).id
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just for completeness, can we see the :acs_object Factory?

Comment: It's very bare-bones, at least so far:  Factory.define :acs_object do |acso|

end

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using fg v. 2.4 in a legacy Rails 2.3.9 app.

Answer (score 0):

factory_girl assumes you want to use the same build class as the parent when you define a child factory. If you don't want to do that, you can override the class in the child definition:

```
Factory.define :content_item, :parent => :acs_object, :class => "ContentItem" do |ci|
  ci.sequence(:name) {|n| "Music#{n}"}
end
```